# c#: Add element to second nesting in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML which looks like:

```
<users>
  <user id="0">
    <name>John</name>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    <bills>
      <bill id="0">
        <name>Water</name>
        <forMonth>2013-12-01</forMonth>
        <money>235</money>
        <lastDayToPay>2014-01-02</lastDayToPay>
        <payed>False</payed>
      </bill>
      <bill id="1">
        <name>Telephone</name>
        <forMonth>2013-11-01</forMonth>
        <money>690</money>
        <lastDayToPay>2014-01-01</lastDayToPay>
        <payed>True</payed>
      </bill>
    </bills>
  </user>
```

How can i add new bill for the user, i have problem accessing "bills" node and adding element to it. I'm using c#.

Comment: Look at `System.Xml.Linq` [XDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi @Carl, I've noticed you making a lot of suggested edits of low or dubious quality. Adding tags like `if-statement` or `nested` to questions is completely pointless; those tags add zero value or searchability. Please don't do that; refer to the editing guidelines to check what is regarded a good suggested edit instead, for example [How do I correctly tag my questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878) Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka웃 Hmm I see what your after and from your POV I do agree. But there are people like myself searching for these tag belive it or not. I use them to mostly to illustrate common problems programmers run into. Otherwise they wouldn't be tags created by the SO community. I read the article you supplied to me good read.. but I think you focus to much on the value adding from YOUR pov. I always read the question and study the problem, and if theres a problem with a nested or and if-statement why not tag it. I mean when are those questions ever going to be tagged otherwise with those tags??

Comment: @Carl thanks for your response. Apparently, the community consensus is that [`if-statement` is a valid tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96219), so fair enough, even though I can't think of a valid situation where that would ever come up in a search. But `Nested`, `uri`, and many of your other additions are much more dubious IMO. Plus the key word is already present in those questions anyway, so you're not improving searchability. If in doubt, it might be worth asking on Meta. (cont'd)

Comment: But either way, a suggested edit is [supposed to address *all* the problems in a question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153074) Don't edit just the tag in while leaving [other grievous problems](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21439296/revisions) in place.

Comment: I started a Meta question: [Where do we draw the line on esoteric tag additions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217932)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Way to go on starting the question. You are totally right in the cases where the word I happen to tag are already present in the title or the question itself. I do somehow believe it's in peoples nature to search for either the title via the search field top right or by pressing a tag and looking through the questions that shows up there. If I'm not misstaken a question having not been tagged by uri, wont show up among other uri tags if not tagged that way. I personally never search up in the right, as I'm still kinda new in the business I dont know the names of everything yet..

Comment: @Carl the search will look in both the tags and the question title/body, I believe. And I can't think of a single real-world situation where one would search for `if-statement` or `nested`... but let's see what the Meta question brings up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following code

```
            XmlDocument myDocument = new XmlDocument();
            myDocument.Load(XMLFile);
            XmlNode newNode = myDocument.CreateElement("bill");
            //add values;
            var requiredNode = myDocument.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(o => o.Name == "bills").First();
            requiredNode.AppendChild(newNode);
            myDocument.Save(XMLFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for this one, but is there any chance to get it without using linq? Thanks

Comment: @ajduk nothing in your question says that you cannot use linq? Why do you have that restriction anyways?

Comment: Yes, you can put foreach loop on myDocument.ChildNodes

Comment: If i use var type i don't have AppendChild method available

Comment: ajduk---- I have updated the code,you only need to put first at the end of query